Why can't I get around 'error: flexible array member' with fixed size union?
Can someone explain why this doesn't work? Below is a simple example of what I'm trying to do. I don't need an explanation on error: flexible array member. I understand that if int g[] is not at the end of the struct, there is ambiguity about the size of the struct that needs to be allocated. In my mind though, creating a union with a particular size seems to get around this. The union here is 100 bytes, so if I use the union, then there shouldn't be ambiguity about the structs size.
My expectation is that the struct S, by default will be evaluated as 204 bytes.
I'm dealing with this problem because I'm using some C code in a C++ project. When the C code is compiled in a C context, this code compiles and works as I've described. But in C++, I get the error: flexible array member error.
I'm trying to explore all options before refactoring the C code and I'm trying to understand why the C++ compiler doesn't allow this while the C compiler does.
struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct B {
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    int g[];
};

union U {
    B b;
    A a;
    uint8_t arr[100];
};

struct S {
    int b;
    U u1;
    U u2;
};

int main()
{
    U u = {{0}};
    S s = {0};

    printf("size=%lu\n", sizeof(U));

    return 0;
}


error
error: flexible array member ‘B::g’ not at end of ‘struct S’


Be very clear about the language. Flexible array members are not available in Standard C++, so you're at the mercy of the compiler writers as to what they do and how they behave.

I'm trying to understand why the C++ compiler doesn't allow this while the C compiler does -- Because C and C++ are two different languages.

In C flexible array members work by being at the very end of the structure. You allocate more storage than the structure needs and simply write past the end of the structure when you're using it. If the member's not the last item in the struct, they cannot work. In struct S the flexible array that may  be at the end of u1 cannot be at the end of S, so trying to use the flexible member could write over u2. And Bono isn't gonna like that.

The shown code does not compile as C.

If you want to use C code in a C++ project then you should compile it as C.  You will then also need to provide external declarations with C linkage by which the C++ code will call the C functions.
